# sql add object to array

Tags: arrays, object, addition, hsqldb

How can I add an object to an array in sql?

I'm searching something like:

```
UPDATE Test SET Column = OldObjects + NewObject
```

I'm using an integer array.

DBMS: HSQLDB 2.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an object to the end of the array if you find the length.

```
UPDATE Test SET Column[CARDINALITY(Column) + 1] = NewObject
```

You can add an array to the end of the array

```
UPDATE Test SET Column = Column || NewArray
```

Comment: `SET Column = Column || ARRAY[CAST (? AS INTEGER)]` worked! - thanks @fredt